# Android MaterialCardView's drop shadow/elevation disappears when rotating it 180 degrees

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-xml, android-cardview

**Summarize the problem:**

I am working on a paint app, and in this app, the user has the option to rotate the canvas, this feature can be useful in some scenarios.

The problem I am having, is that when I rotate the `CardView`, which hosts the canvas/bitmap, 180 degrees -- the drop shadow gets lost. I do not get this problem when I rotate the `CardView` 90 degrees, only 180 degrees.

**Describe what you've tried**

I've tried many things, such as giving the CardView more space so that the drop shadow will show, or manually applying drop shadow from the code after rotating it 180 degrees, but it hasn't worked.

**Show some code**

Here is the code responsible for rotating the `CardView` (it's really simple):

```
fun CanvasActivity.rotate(rotationValue: RotationValue, animate: Boolean = false) {
    rotate(rotationValue.degrees, rotationValue.clockwise, animate)
}

fun CanvasActivity.rotate(degrees: Int, clockwise: Boolean = true, animate: Boolean = false) {
    val rotationAmount = if (clockwise) {
        (binding.activityCanvasCardView.rotation + degrees)
    } else {
        (binding.activityCanvasCardView.rotation - degrees)
    }

    if (animate) {
        binding.activityCanvasCardView
            .animate()
            .rotation(rotationAmount)
    } else {
        binding.activityCanvasCardView.rotation = rotationAmount
    }
}
```

`activity_canvas`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fragment_background_color_daynight"
    tools:context=".activities.canvas.CanvasActivity">
    <!-- This view is here to ensure that when the user zooms in, there is no overlap -->
    <View
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:outlineProvider="none"
        android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_topView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@color/fragment_background_color_daynight"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- The ColorSwitcherView is a view I created which helps
         simplify the code for controlling the user's primary/secondary color -->
    <com.therealbluepandabear.pixapencil.customviews.colorswitcherview.ColorSwitcherView
        android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_colorSwitcherView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:outlineProvider="none"
        app:isPrimarySelected="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/activityCanvas_topView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activityCanvas_colorPickerRecyclerView" />

    <!-- The user's color palette data will be displayed in this RecyclerView -->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:outlineProvider="none"
        android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_colorPickerRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activityCanvas_topView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/activityCanvas_colorSwitcherView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activityCanvas_primaryFragmentHost"
        tools:listitem="@layout/color_picker_layout" />

    <!-- This FrameLayout is crucial when it comes to the calculation of the TransparentBackgroundView and PixelGridView -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_distanceContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/activityCanvas_tabLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/activityCanvas_primaryFragmentHost"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activityCanvas_topView" />

    <!-- This gives both views (the PixelGridView and TransparentBackgroundView) a nice drop shadow -->
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_cardView"
        style="@style/activityCanvas_canvasFragmentHostCardViewParent_style"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/activityCanvas_tabLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activityCanvas_topView">
        <!-- At runtime, the width and height of the TransparentBackgroundView and PixelGridView will be calculated -->
       <com.therealbluepandabear.pixapencil.customviews.transparentbackgroundview.TransparentBackgroundView
            android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_transparentBackgroundView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />

        <com.therealbluepandabear.pixapencil.customviews.pixelgridview.PixelGridView
            android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_pixelGridView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <!-- The primary tab layout -->
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:outlineProvider="none"
        android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tabStripEnabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/activityCanvas_viewPager2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/activityCanvas_tab_tools_str" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/activityCanvas_tab_filters_str" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/activityCanvas_tab_color_palettes_str" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/activityCanvas_tab_brushes_str" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <!-- This view allows move functionality -->
    <View
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:outlineProvider="none"
        android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_moveView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activityCanvas_distanceContainer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activityCanvas_topView" />

    <!-- The tools, palettes, brushes, and filters fragment will be displayed inside this ViewPager -->
    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:outlineProvider="none"
        android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_viewPager2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activityCanvas_primaryFragmentHost"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <!-- This CoordinatorLayout is responsible for ensuring that the app's snackbars can be swiped -->
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:outlineProvider="none"
        android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <!-- All of the full page fragments will be displayed in this fragment host -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:outlineProvider="none"
        android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_primaryFragmentHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

0 degrees:

[image]

90 degrees:

[image]

180 degrees:

[image]

As you can see, no drop shadow when it's rotated 180 degrees (when the origin is 0 degrees).

This problem is not major but it makes the UI of my app inconsistent.

**Note: for some reason, I only get the issue on phones but not tablet devices.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a curious thing, actually. I've tried to rotate a simple shadowed View and it seems that it cuts off the shadow when it has 180/-180 rotation angle without any logical reason. I also tried to play with outline providers, buut no. So it's not about CardView, it rather comes from the implementation of drawing a shadow in the View class.

I've searched a bit, and it was already reported directly to Google and fixed, but probably some compat libraries still have this issue that's why you're facing it.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173730323

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137454913

I can suggest you creating a crutch (yeap, I know, that it's not a solution) with leaving a comment. If your rotation is about -180/180, you can "normalize" it with "-179.9/179.9". In terms of the user experience it won't be visible, in terms of beautiful code - meh, but I don't see any other ways here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- I marked it as the solution. You said some compat libraries still have the issue, what compat libraries then? I am not using much compat libraries in the app as it runs on 8.0+. And when will it get fixed for compat libraries do you think?

Comment: @thebluepandabear to be honest, I don't know about their time estimations regarding any issues - as well as which the exact library could cause such a behaviour. You can create an issue on the same issue tracker I've mentioned, but it usually takes some time until Google is coming up with a fix, unfortunately.

Comment: Update some time later: your workaround is great, but I've discovered 2-3 new bugs to do with this workaround -- if you rotate a view 179.9 once and then rotate it 179.9 again the rotation slowly loses accuracy and 'skews'. I have fixed this issue but the codebase has been completely destroyed. I have created a new issue request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/244770411 in regards to this issue not being fixed in Android yet.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `android:outlineProvider="none"` on most items ...
while the drop-shadow being used might have the wrong offset coordinates - you'd need to substract instead of adding the offset. There's too little code provided to answer this more accurately - but with high probability, the shadow is just hidden underneath the canvas, due to the stated cause. I'd suggest to provide your own implementation of [`ViewOutlineProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewOutlineProvider) and then pass this instead of `none`.

Comment: I do not think that it's the cause of the issue. When I remove `ViewOutlineProvider` entirely, the issue still resides. I had the issue for many months prior to adding the `android:outlineProvider="none"`. But, I'll take a look again at the code to make sure. If it was the case, I'd expect the issue to also be reflected when I rotate the canvas 90 degrees as well, so what you're saying is - imo - unlikely.

Comment: You created the problem with `android:outlineProvider="none"` and it's unclear where you even set the drop-shadow's offset values. The business logic used for the calculation of the offsets for the shadow is definitely flawed. This might work for device rotation, but not for view with drop-shadow rotation. It may as well be the style being applied, which ignores the fact, that the view had been rotated - and then still provides the offset values, as if nothing happened. "show layout boundaries" should confirm this.

Comment: And actually, the drop-shadow should always be the same ...no matter of the content rotation... so the answer might be, not to rotate the shadow, but only the contained canvas (just wrap that XML node). In reality, the position of the desk lamp will not change either, when rotating the canvas.

Comment: If I rotate the contents of the `CardView` I don't get the animation I want, but thanks anyways.

Comment: Hey, what's more strange, is that I'm only getting this issue on phones, but not on tablets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set total (left, right, bottom and top) of 16dp on each side `android:layout_margin="16dp"` and set `app:cardElevation="4dp"`, it will work.

Comment: I set that in the style already though... I'll take a look again though, cheers.